# How do I implement, for instance, "group membership" many-to-many in Parse.com REST Cloud Code?

Tags: api, rest, associations, parse-platform

A user can create groups
A group had to have created by a user

A user can belong to multiple groups
A group can have multiple users

I have something like the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Group', function(request) {

var creator = request.user;
var group = request.object;
var wasGroupCreated = group.existed;

if(wasGroupCreated) {

    var hasCreatedRelation = creator.relation('hasCreated');
    hasCreatedRelation.add(group);

    var isAMemberOfRelation = creator.relation('isMemberOf');
    isAMemberOfRelation.add(group);

    creator.save();
}
});
```

Now when I GET user/me with include=isMemberOf,hasCreated, it returns me the user object but with the following:

```
hasCreated: {
__type: "Relation"
className: "Group"
},
isMemberOf: {
__type: "Relation"
className: "Group"
}
```

I'd like to have the group objects included in say, 'hasCreated' and 'isMemberOf' arrays. How do I pull that using the REST API?

More in general though, am I approaching this the right way? Thoughts? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: review docs Rest API / Roles /Creating roles and follow the example using curl and using the parse browser to check your work on the _User table . I think it will help with your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `existed` is a function that returns true or false (in your case the `wasGroupCreated` variable is always going to be a reference to the function and will tis always evaluate to true). It probably isn't going to return what you expect anyway if you were using it correctly.

I think what you want is the `isNew()` function, though I would test if this works in the `Parse.Cloud.afterSave()` method as I haven't tried it there.

As for the second part of your question, you seem to want to use your Relations like Arrays. If you used an array instead (and the size was small enough), then you could just include the `Group` objects in the query (add `include` parameter set to `isMemberOf` for example in your REST query).

If you do want to stick to Relations, realise that you'll need to read up more in the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-relational). In particular you'll need to query the `Group` object using a `where` expression that has a `$relatedTo` pointer for the user. To query in this manner, you will probably need a `members` property on the `Group` that is a relation to `Users`.

Something like this in your REST query might work (replace the objectId with the right User of course):

```
where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"8TOXdXf3tz"},"key":"members"}}
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for the comment! The first one was pretty stupid. I just fixed that! I have implemented what you are suggesting to get the sets of groups separately using the where clauses for key: 'isMemberOf' and key: 'hasCreated'. I was wondering whether I can make one query to _User and get the full group objects right inside of the _User response. Right now a GET to /me gives: 

..."hasCreated":{"__type":"Relation","className":"Group"},"isMemberOf":{"__type":"Relation","className":"Group"}...

I was wondering these can be full objects.

Comment: If you use an Array instead of a Relation, then you can use `include` to fully load the objects. With a Relation you can't do that unfortunately.

Comment: How do I edit the above afterSave to implement arrays instead? Is it as simple as having array fields in _User and then just do:

    creator.hasCreated.push(group) ?

Comment: So, the error I'm seeing is that creator.get('hasCreated') is undefined when I try to do hasCreated = creator.get('hasCreated'); hasCreated.push(group); creator.set('hasCreated', hasCreated); where hacCreated is an array field in creator. Thoughts?

Comment: Okay, the problem is solved. Just found out from API Docs that I needed to use user.addUnique('isMemberOf', group), where is 'isMemberOf' is an array field in _User. Now when I do GET on /user/ with param: include:isMemberOf,hasCreated, I'm getting full group objects back. Thanks Tim for your help!